# Gradle, Gulp, Sass - Missing node-sass binding

Tags: gradle, gulp, gulp-sass

I am attempting to run a gradle build which runs my gulp build. I want to be able to use a specific version of node (0.12.7) to do the build, but I have node 0.10.x installed on my local machine.

However, when I run a gradle clean build, I get the following error:

```
Error: Missing binding C:\myapp\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-x64-14\binding.node
Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: Windows 64-bit with Node 0.12.x

Found bindings for the following environments:
  - Windows 64-bit with Node 0.10.x

This usually happens because your environment has changed since running `npm install`.
```

gradle setup:

```
    plugins {
    id "java"
    id "idea"
    id "maven"
    id "com.moowork.node" version "0.12"
    id "com.moowork.gulp" version "0.12"
}

    // configure gradle-node-plugin
node {
    version = '0.12.7'
    download = true
}

// clean node/node_modules/typings
task npmClean(type: Delete) {
    delete "${rootDir}/node_modules"
}

gulp_dev.dependsOn installGulp
gulp_dev.dependsOn npmInstall
build.dependsOn(gulp_dev)
clean.dependsOn(npmClean)
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: The task dependency example on node plugin github page uses an underscore in `npmInstall`, can you try `gulp_dev.dependsOn npm_Install` ?

Comment: Thanks for for the suggestion, but it did not solve the problem.

Comment: do you know which particular task throws your error? Is there a dependency between installGulp and npmInstall about which should run first?

Comment: It is my gulp_dev task which throws the error. I followed the readme from the gradle gulp plugin: https://github.com/srs/gradle-gulp-plugin

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your issue. Can you share a simplified example that causes this issue?

Comment: @RaGe The problem occurs for me when I have different version of node installed locally to what is specified in my gradle script. After gradle kicks off npm install and attempts to run my gulp tasks, it fails, I assume when attempting to run gulp sass.

Perhaps I can get an example project in github over the next couple of days (time permitting!).

Comment: so the way I tried it, i didn't have local node installed at all. gradle plugin downloaded node, ran npm-install and then gulp tasks, without issue.